# What is the id of the actionbar navigation icon?

Tags: android

I am doing this in my activity but it does not open the drawer. But it tracks the clicks, I think the id is wrong.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "CLICK" + v.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
            break;
    }
}
```

If you're going to ask, the id being displayed in the toast is -1.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html hope that will help you